# How to insert value in one sublist from another in the same parent list object

Tags: python, list

I have a list of track start times in a long audio file.  I use ffmpeg to split it up, but it requires a little text wrangling to feed it properly to ffmpeg.  The list might look like this:

```
0:00 first track
3:23 second track
8:47 third track
11:23 fourth track
```

I need to get it to look like this:

```
00:00:00 00:03:23 first_track
00:03:23 00:08:47 second_track
00:08:47 00:11:23 third_track
00:11:23 00:14:31 fourth_track (and so on)
```

So far, I'm doing this (omitting the obvious code to set the file):

```
import re

t_format = re.compile("..:..:..")  # hh:mm:ss

playlist = []
with open(filein, 'r') as pl:
    lines = (line.rstrip() for line in pl)
    lines = list(line for line in lines if line)

    for l in lines:
        t_in = l[:8]
        if not bool(re.match(t_format, t_in)):
            newline = t_in.split(' ')[0]
            if len(newline) == 4:
                newline = '00:0' + newline
                fixed_line = [newline, l[5:]]
                playlist.append(fixed_line)
            elif len(newline) == 5:
                newline = '00:' + newline
                fixed_line = [newline, l[6:]]
                playlist.append(fixed_line)
            elif len(newline) == 7:
                newline = '0' + newline
                fixed_line = [newline, l[8:]]
                playlist.append(fixed_line)
        else:
            playlist.append(l)
```

I know it's not beautiful but it works, providing me something like this

```
['00:00:00', 'first track'],['00:03:23', 'second track']...
```

From here, what's the best way to grab position `[0]` value in the next list object, and insert it as position `[1]` in the current list object?  I do understand the list `.insert()` function, just not how to get the value of the following list position.

Comment: what about the last element in the list? and also the sample data you posted is not a list

Comment: the last one will have the total track time in position 1.  I can fetch that separately from the rest.  So I'll just have to iterate until that (or put it all in a try/except)

Comment: are you reading data from file?

Comment: Sure, here it is. Note this is the output list from the text file: https://pastebin.com/AqxMmg7d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip()`

> **Note:** This will not add the last element of list to result.

```
data = [['00:00:00', 'Final Fantasy IV - The Prelude -- Shiro Satou'], ['00:03:36', 'EarthBound - Theme of Winters -- Tomoko Kataoka'], ['00:06:41', 'Super Mario 64 - Dire, Dire Docks -- The Altered Beasts'], ['00:11:01', 'Suikoden III - Amidst the Sunlit Trees -- difï½¥ref'], ['00:15:47', 'Donkey Kong Country - Cry of the Chasmal Critter Chain -- ella guro'], ['00:20:47', 'Etrian Odyssey - Scene - Blue and White -- Takahiro Izutani'], ['00:24:41', 'The Legend of Zelda: Ocarina of Time - Fragments of a Legend -- WillRock'], ['00:27:34', 'Mega Man 9 - Splash Blue -- Luna Umegaki'], ['00:31:53', 'Final Fantasy VII - Where Destiny Meets -- Joshua Morse'], ['00:34:51', 'Metroid Prime 2 - Torvus Clockwork -- DarkeSword'], ['00:39:17', 'Castle Crashers - Winterbliss -- David Cookie'], ['00:42:58', 'Donkey Kong Country 2 - Stickerbush Symphony -- PPF'], ['00:47:35', 'Animal Crossing: Wild World - Moonlit Memories -- ectogemia'], ['00:50:09', "Kirby's Adventure - Plenty of Butter Building -- Hirokazu Ando"], ['00:53:29', 'Ys - Opening -- WATAMIN'], ['00:57:18', "The Legend of Zelda: Link's Awakening - Dreams of Home -- Chris ~ Amaterasu, waltzforluma"], ['00:59:51', '7th Dragon - Labyrinth - Jungle Navigation -- Norihiko Hibino'], ['01:04:39', 'Final Fantasy VI - Katabasis -- Forrest Powell, Laura Intravia'], ['01:09:14', 'Mother 3 - Flowers -- Shogo Sakai'], ['01:13:34', 'Okami - Waka Appears -- Hiroshi Yamaguchi'], ['01:16:24', 'Unlimited Saga - The Seven Travelers -- Sword of the Far East'], ['01:19:51', "Chrono Trigger - Corridor of Time ~ Schala's Theme -- Drakskip"], ['01:25:45', 'Tales of Phantasia - Magical Forest Medley -- RebeccaETripp'], ['01:30:06', 'PokÃ©mon X & Y - Thy Everlasting Winter Wind Blows -- timaeus222'], ['01:33:04', 'Final Fantasy V - La Princesa de Taikun ~Theme of Lenna~ -- Sixto Sounds'], ['01:37:18', 'Super Mario RPG - Booster Tower -- The OneUps'], ['01:42:38', 'Undertale - Like Snowflakes -- Ace Waters'], ['01:47:40', 'Final Fantasy X - People Of The Far North -- Masashi Hamauzu'], ['01:51:42', 'Kingdom Hearts - Respite -- Emunator'], ['01:54:11', 'Chrono Cross - Radical Dreamers -- Hiroaki Yura, Minah Choe, Zane Banks'], ['01:58:38', 'Final Fantasy IX - Over the Hill -- TPR'], ['02:03:38', 'Wild Arms - Relief for the Wanderer -- Pot Hocket'], ['02:07:08', 'DoDonPachi Daifukkatsu - Stage 5 -- Kohta Takahashi'], ['02:11:41', 'Metroid Prime 3 - Entropic Dream -- Laura Intravia, Pyro Paper Planes'], ['02:16:08', "The Legend of Zelda: Majora's Mask - Dawn of a New Dream -- Radiowar"], ['02:19:27', 'NieR - Emil / Piano Ver. -- Keigo Hoashi'], ['02:23:25', "Secret of Mana - Mana's Requiem -- Pixel Noise"], ['02:26:55', 'Suikoden - An Old Irish Song -- rain book'], ['02:31:03', 'Phoenix Wright: Ace Attorney - Trials and Tribulations - Godot ~ The Fragrance of Dark Coffee -- Noriyuki Iwadare'], ['02:36:56', 'Yume Nikki - Dark Ages -- Kiichi'], ['02:40:23', "PokÃ©mon Red & Blue - The Bane of Kanto (Gotta Kill 'em All) -- The OneUps"], ['02:44:17', 'Final Fantasy XV - Veiled in Black -- GENTLE LOVE'], ['02:51:20', 'Madara 2 - Final Movement ~ A Brilliant Funeral Procession -- Yuji Yoshino, Aki Hata'], ['02:55:14', 'Etrian Odyssey IV - On an Adventure Gliding Through the Skies -- Noriyuki Kamikura'], ['02:58:16', 'Shenmue - Amorelle -- Radiowar']]
times, titles = zip(*data)
for x in zip(times, times[1:], titles):
    print(' '.join(x))
```

You can also use [itertools.zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)

```
from itertools import zip_longest

times, titles = zip(*data)
res = list(map(list, zip_longest(times, times[1:], titles)))
```

If you use `zip_longest()` it will include last element also. Then you can update the ending time of last element using

```
res[-1][1] = '#time'
```

Comment: use `zip_longest` from `itertools` to also fill in the last slot. Or maybe even easier, use `collections.deque` on one of the lists and "rotate" it once

Comment: I know but OP doesn't mention the second time value for last element

Comment: thanks for this, will have to spend some time getting more familiar with zip - @exhuma the last value is derived from the audio file itself and has to be fetched separately, since it will not be in the original text file